# Finding the function when the second derivative is defined in terms of it.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, functions

So I was playing around with derivatives and I realized that I could find a function when it's derivative was given in terms of it. But when I tried this with a second derivative I couldn't find the function.

Is there any way to solve for $f(x)$ in this equation?
$$ \frac {d^2f}{dx^2} = (f(x))^{-2}$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** For differential equation of form $f''=F(f,f')$, the standard track is set $v=f'$, then we have
$$
f''=\frac{\text dv}{\text dx}=\frac{\text dv}{\text df}\frac{\text df}{\text dx}=v\frac{\text dv}{\text df},
$$

then we get
$$
v\frac{\text dv}{\text df}=f^{-2}.
$$

Answer (score 0):

$$y''=\frac 1 {y^2}$$
Multiply by $2y'$
$$2 y''y'=2\frac {y'}{y^2}$$

$$(y'^2)'=-2(y^{-1})'$$
Then integrate
$$y'^2=K-2y^{-1}$$